# Saving checkbox selected values into Sqlite database-Android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, checkbox

In my Android app i have screen with Table matrix (corresponding screenshot as shown in below).I have designed for each row i used a linear layout set as horizantal with TextView and Checkboxes.So, i have designed for all rows in the same way.

Now, i have Strucked at how to create and insert a table using Sqlite Database in android for getting a value of selected checkbox with this type of view.

For an Example, In design view, 0th row (TASK 1) and 0th column (WEEKS means Sunday,Monday,Tuesday and so on), If an user selects Task1 with Sunday Checkbox then i want  to get that particular action ID and Value (selected Checkbox Value).And also we have to save a multiple selected checkboxes values into SQlite Database.

I am New Android Developer So Please Help Me On This.

THANK YOU.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ln0QV.png)

Comment: A possible solution is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24174625/3800164)

Comment: Create checboxes dynamically